# Adding Link file using APACHE POI XSSF is not accepting directory address and showing java.net.URISyntaxException

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

I am trying to hyperlink a .png file in a cell content of any .xlsx file. Following is the part of code and it is showing java.net.URISyntaxException exception (seems because of slash used in the address). However changing link.setAddress("test.png") is not showing any error, but it is not resolving my purpose. Please help me.

```
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
       XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
       CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
       CellStyle hlink_style = wb.createCellStyle();
       Font hlink_font = wb.createFont();
       hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
       hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
       hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
       XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Hyperlinks");
        XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(1).createCell((short)0);
       cell.setCellValue("File Link");
       Hyperlink link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
       link.setAddress("H:\\Selenium\\XL\\src\\santosh\\xlwork\\test.png");
       cell.setHyperlink(link);
       cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("hyperlinks.xlsx");
       wb.write(out);
       out.close();
    }
```

Ultimately what I need to do is to hyperlink a screenshot with any cell. The screenshot directory will be anywhere other than eclipse workspace.

Comment: `H:\blah` isn't a valid URI though, so that the exception seems correct. Have you tried with `file:///H:/....` - the correct way to encode that sort of path as a URL

Comment: I have tried with 
link.setAddress("file:///H:/Selenium/XL/src/santosh/xlwork/test.png");
but it is showing IOException with error message, "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: If you create the link in Excel, then read it back in POI, how did the link end up getting written to the file?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Your Idea finally work to find and debug the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have done this ...Thanks to Gagravarr... Given me a good Idea.

```
boolean isDirCreated = false;//to create Screenshot directory just once

//Create Screenshot Directory.
public static void createDir(String ScreenshotDirAddress){
    if(!isDirCreated){
       File file= new File(ScreenshotDirAddress);
       if (!file.exists())
            file.mkdirs();
    isDirCreated=true;
    }
}


//hyperlink screenshot
public static void hyperlinkScreenshot(XSSFCell cell, String FileAddress){
    XSSFWorkbook wb=cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook();
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    CellStyle hlink_style = wb.createCellStyle();
    Font hlink_font = wb.createFont();
    hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
    hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
    Hyperlink hp = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
    FileAddress=FileAddress.replace("\\", "/");
    hp.setAddress(FileAddress);
    cell.setHyperlink(hp);
    cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
}

//take screenshot
public static void takeScreenShot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName, XSSFCell cell){
    createDir();
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        String FullAddress=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+ScreenshotDirAddress+"/"+screenshotName+".png";
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(FullAddress));
        hyperlinkScreenshot(cell, FullAddress);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Main problem that I have faced was related to the URL. If I used "\" it is showing illegalArgumentException, while replacing it with "/" is working fine. I don't know the exact reason but if

```
        FileAddress=FileAddress.replace("\\", "/");
```

is commented... it is showing illegal argument exception. So if the URL is

***D:\eclipse\workspace\TestApp\Screenshot\TestResult\Test.png***

will show the illegalArgumentException. However if "\" is replaced by "/" to make it 
    ***D:/eclipse/workspace/TestApp/Screenshot/TestResult/Test.png***

it is working properly. Both the URL is correct and opening the same file in browser or even using manually in excel file for hyperlink the same file its working fine. I don't know why it is showing exception in Apache POI, may be a possible Bug.

Comment: Might be handy if you also gave the final URL in text, to help people only skim-reading to see what they need to aim for

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String takeScreenShot(XSSFRow wrow, XSSFCell cell,String fileName)
    {
        try {

            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();    
            fileName = fileName + dtf.format(now);
            fileName=fileName.replace(":","");

            File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            String screen_path;
            ReadConfigProperty file = new ReadConfigProperty();
            FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("Screenshot\\" + fileName + ".jpg"));
            screen_path= file.reportFilePath() + fileName + ".jpg";


            screen_path= "file:///"+screen_path;

            cell = wrow.createCell(7);
            //cell.setCellValue(screen_path);


            XSSFWorkbook wb=cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook();
            CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
            XSSFCellStyle hlink_style = wb.createCellStyle();
            XSSFFont hlink_font = wb.createFont();
            hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
            hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
            hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
            Hyperlink hp = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
            screen_path=screen_path.replace("\\", "/");
            hp.setAddress(screen_path);
            cell.setHyperlink((org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Hyperlink) hp);
            cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);

            return screen_path;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileName;

    }
```