# How to link a image from excel file using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am writting some text say "**Pass**" into excel file using `cell.setCellValue("Pass")`. Now I have  to create a link to an image which locates at directory *(C:\Users\UserName\DeskTop\image\test.jpg)* from an excel.

When I click on text pass from excel file, then it should open the `test.jpg` image.

Please guide me/share to JAVA code to achieve this.

Thanks,
Md Ashfaq

Comment: I am using Java code to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ashfaq...Following is a method you can user for hyperlink the screenshot with the cell.

```
 public static void hyperlinkScreenshot(XSSFCell cell, String FileAddress){
    XSSFWorkbook wb=cell.getRow().getSheet().getWorkbook();
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    CellStyle hlink_style = wb.createCellStyle();
    Font hlink_font = wb.createFont();
    hlink_font.setUnderline(Font.U_SINGLE);
    hlink_font.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());
    hlink_style.setFont(hlink_font);
    Hyperlink hp = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
    FileAddress=FileAddress.replace("\\", "/");
    hp.setAddress(FileAddress);
    cell.setHyperlink(hp);
    cell.setCellStyle(hlink_style);
}
```

for details [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15934650/624003).

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "C:\Users\UserName\DeskTop\image\test.jpg", TextToDisplay:="pass"
```

You can remove the setvalue as TextToDisplay can handle this...

Comment: i used the same code but its giving errors in eclipse. I am new to this POI, can u re-write the complete code with more clarity. I am using cell = row.createCell(Colposition) to get the cell value