# Unable to open hyperlinked files in Excel with JAVA using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I'm trying to open all the files that are linked in an Excel Sheet using Apache POI. This is what I've got:

```
FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file);
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputstream);

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
log("Processing Sheet: " + sheet.getSheetName());

Iterator rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
    HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
    Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cellIterator.next();

        if(cell.getHyperlink() != null){
            HSSFHyperlink hyperlink = cell.getHyperlink();
            log("Hyperlink found: " + hyperlink.getAddress());
            try{
                FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(hyperlink.getAddress());
            }catch(Exception ex){
                log(ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But `hyperlink.getAddress()` doesn't return the correct path, it looks like it returns the relative path but without `../`.

I also tried using the `getDirectoryRoot()` method on the workbook. But that just returns `/`. I have the path to my Excel file but without the base path that the excel uses or the `../`'s in the attachments path, I'm not able to get the correct path.

Comment: Check this....http://stackoverflow.com/q/15934650/624003 I think that will be helpful for you...

Comment: @Sankumarsingh, thanks but that's for writing hyperlinks to the file. I need to read them and get the file from the hyperlink address. I can read the hyperlink address but I'm not able to open the file. The problem is that Excel uses relative paths... I can solve it by changing this setting to absolute but that is not exactly what I need...

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use one easier way: Take a file with that relative address and then get the absolute path of that file.

e.g.

```
System.out.println(new File(hyperlink.getAddress()).getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: doesn't give the correct path either. Excel uses a really strange way of pointing to files if you do not change the settings ti absolute paths...